# How to rescale a pytorch tensor to interval [0,1]?

Tags: python, pytorch

I would like to rescale a pytorch tensor named `outmap` to the [0, 1] interval. I tried this:

```
outmap_min = torch.min(outmap, dim=1, keepdim=True)
outmap_max = torch.max(outmap, dim=1, keepdim=True)
outmap = (outmap - outmap_min) / (outmap_max - outmap_min)
```

And I am getting this error:
`TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for -: 'Tensor' and 'torch.return_types.min'`

Comment: Depending on what you're trying to do I can think of different ways. For example, you can apply sigmoid activation, softmax or normalization to the outputs.

Answer (score 3):

There are many ways to answer the question posed in your title (e.g., min-max normalization, or one of many non-linear functions mapping (-infinity, infinity) to [0, 1]). Based on the context of the post, I'm assuming you just want to implement min-max normalization.

`torch.min()` does not return a tensor; it returns a type akin to a tuple (and in fact the [documentation](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/generated/torch.min.html) says it's a namedtuple). It's a two-tuple; the first element is the tensor you're looking for (min), and the second element is an indexing tensor specifying the indices of the minimum values (argmin). The same goes for `torch.max()`.

So, suppose your tensor is of size `[N, M]`. If you're trying to min-max normalize each "row" (dimension 0) based on the min and max of the `M` elements (columns) in that row, you'd compute the min and max along dimension 1. This would give you `N` mins and `N` maxes -- a min and max for each row. You'd then apply the normalization. This is what your code was intended to do, but you have to unpack the return values of `torch.min()` and `torch.max()`, discarding the argmin and argmax in this case:

```
outmap_min, _ = torch.min(outmap, dim=1, keepdim=True)
outmap_max, _ = torch.max(outmap, dim=1, keepdim=True)
outmap = (outmap - outmap_min) / (outmap_max - outmap_min) # Broadcasting rules apply
```

If your tensor is of size `[N, ...]`, where `...` indicates an arbitrary number of dimensions each of arbitrary size, and you want to min-max normalize each row as before, then the solution is a bit more tricky. Unfortunately, `torch.min()` and `torch.max()` each only accept a single dimension. If you want to compute extrema along multiple dimensions, you either have to call `torch.min()` / `torch.max()` once for each dimension, or you have to reshape / flatten your tensor so that all of the targeted dimensions are merged into one. So if your tensor is of size `[N, ...]`, it just has to be reshaped to size `[N, R, 1, 1, ...]`, where `R` is the product of the sizes of the remaining dimensions, and the 1's preserve the *number* of dimensions (this makes broadcasting easier later). For instance, if your tensor is of size `[N, A, B, C]`, you should reshape it to size `[N, A*B*C, 1, 1]`. Following that, you can compute mins / maxes along the R-sized dimension 1, as before:

```
flattened_outmap = outmap.view(outmap.shape[0], -1, 1, 1) # Use 1's to preserve the number of dimensions for broadcasting later, as explained
outmap_min, _ = torch.min(flattened_outmap, dim=1, keepdim=True)
outmap_max, _ = torch.max(flattened_outmap, dim=1, keepdim=True)
outmap = (outmap - outmap_min) / (outmap_max - outmap_min) # Broadcasting rules apply
```

If you wanted to, you could programmatically construct the placeholder 1's as a list whose length is equal to the number of dimensions minus 2 (to account for the `[N, R]` dimensions)), and then expand the list. e.g.:

```
flattened_outmap = outmap.view(outmap.shape[0], -1, *([1] * (len(outmap.shape) - 2)))
```

In more complicated cases where you want the min / max normalization statistics to be computed across multiple non-contiguous dimensions, you'll probably have to permute the tensor prior to reshaping it. This can't be done with a view, so you'd have to create an extra copy of the tensor. This would surely require more memory than simply calling `torch.min()` / `torch.max()` once per dimension, but the tensorization of it might make it faster (it'd probably depend on the number of dimensions; you'd have to benchmark it).

Comment: Thank you. outmap.size() = torch.Size([250, 300, 300]). Seems like there is incompatability of size in dim1 between outmap and outmap_min (or outmap_max).

Comment: @ReaKalampaliki Good point; thanks. This is because you still need the number of dimensions to match when broadcasting since the trailing dimensions are expanded. In this case, you should use `view()` or `reshape()` rather than `flatten()`, leaving in extra 1's to pad the number of dimensions to assist in broadcasting. I've edited my answer to reflect this, but I don't have time to test it. Let me know if there's something wrong with it.

Comment: Seems like the final outmap is full of nan values.

Comment: Then some of the maxes are probably equal to the mins and you're getting divisions by zero. That, or it's already populated with NaN values prior to normalization. You'll have to decide on some rule for handling divisions by zero (what should they be mapped to? 0? 1? 0.5? This is up to you)

Comment: Yes, there many 0s in outmap. But why min_outmap and max_outmap are tensors of size torch.Size([150, 1, 1]) ?

Comment: What size do you expect them to be? I suggest we move this discussion to [chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/245238/rescaletensor).